# How to extract or compare kSecPropertyKeyValue from SecCertificate

Tags: swift, security, certificate, keychain

Need to parse and compare certificate values, but some of them are returned as `Data` which doesn't parse as a string. Most properties are returned as numbers or strings, but `kSecPropertyKeyValue` is an array of `CFData`. Need this for similar certificate information display as Keychain Access does.

```
import Foundation
import Security

let query: [CFString: Any] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassCertificate,
    kSecReturnAttributes: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecReturnRef: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecReturnData: kCFBooleanTrue,
    kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitAll
]

var result: AnyObject?
SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)
let certs: [SecCertificate] = (result as? [[CFString: Any]])?.map({ $0[kSecValueRef] as! SecCertificate }) ?? []

for cert in certs {
    if let values: [CFString:Any] = (SecCertificateCopyValues(cert, [kSecOIDExtendedKeyUsage] as CFArray, nil) as? [CFString:Any])?[kSecOIDExtendedKeyUsage] as? [CFString:Any] {

        // Expect to find `kSecOIDExtendedUseCodeSigning` value or something else
        // meaningful. How do I do that?

        print(
            "type:", values[kSecPropertyKeyType]!,
            "||| data values:", values[kSecPropertyKeyValue] as! [Data],
            "||| cString:", (values[kSecPropertyKeyValue] as! [CFData]).map({ String(cString: CFDataGetBytePtr($0)) }),
            "||| string:", (values[kSecPropertyKeyValue] as! [Data]).map({ String(data: $0, encoding: .utf8) })
        )
    }
}
```

Paste in a playground, prints:

```
type: array ||| data values: [8 bytes] ||| cString: ["+\u{06}\u{01}\u{05}\u{05}\u{07}\u{03}\u{04}"] ||| string: [Optional("+\u{06}\u{01}\u{05}\u{05}\u{07}\u{03}\u{04}")]
type: array ||| data values: [9 bytes] ||| cString: ["*�H��cd\u{04}\t"] ||| string: [nil]
```

Some look like unicode escapes, some appear like invalid strings. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently OID values don't have readable string representations, but are constants, which can be found in [google/der-ascii](https://github.com/google/der-ascii).

For example, the above output of `+\u{06}\u{01}\u{05}\u{05}\u{07}\u{03}\u{04}` matches `0x2b, 0x06, 0x01, 0x05, 0x05, 0x07, 0x03, 0x04`, which is [email protection](https://github.com/google/der-ascii/blob/cd91cb85bb0d71e4611856e4f76f5110609d7e42/cmd/der2ascii/oid_names.go#L104) (`+` is `0x2b` in bytes).